# No title+multicol+custom ToC: 1: Horizontal alignment of first column. 2: Adjusting lineheight with multi-line entry. 3: Right margin text alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have three issues in my ToC which are illustrated in this picture:
[image]

I have posted a minimal example at the end.

**1: The alignment of the first ToC entry.** I have a ToC with no title, but the space that the title would occupy is still there even without the title content. As can be seen in the minimal example, I have tried to mitigate the problem by inserting a vspace into the title with this line: `\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\vspace{-3cm}}`. I can get it to align, but I really, really, really want a less hacky solution if possible.

**2: The line-spacing of the content of the subentry.** I have found a couple of commands to control the line-spacing between the section title and content and between the entries in the ToC: `\setlength\cftparskip{-5pt}` and `\renewcommand{\cftbeforesectionskip}{3pt}`, but I cannot find the right command to adjust the line-spacing of the content.

**3: Bad right margin alignment.** There is a weird issue with the right margin alignment in the ToC. It seems like the text width of the content is smaller than the columns, except for the last entry (Section 5 as seen below). I would like the content to align justified with the margins of the columns, such that the text width of all of the entries correspond to something like the last entry.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[danish]{isodate}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\vspace{-3cm}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\itshape\scriptsize}
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape\scriptsize}
  \renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}[2]{%
    \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}}%
    \leftskip=0.0cm%
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg%
    \parfillskip=\fill%
    \ifhmode\ \else\noindent\fi%
    \ignorespaces{\cftsubsubsectionfont ##1.}%
    \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
  \let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth%
  \let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext%
  \let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum\addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
\sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}%
\setrmarg{2em}%
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{0em}%
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries\scriptsize}%
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesectionskip}{3pt}%
}%

\let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum%
\addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}%
\let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum\addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}%
\setlength\cftparskip{-5pt}%

\newcommand{\Sum}[1]{%
{{\itshape#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\makefirstuc{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\TOCcols}{%
\begin{multicols}{3}%
\setupmaintoc%
\tableofcontents*%
\end{multicols}%
}%

\newtotcounter{SECTION}
\setcounter{SECTION}{0}

\begin{document}

\setupparasubsubsecs%
\clearpage%
\mainmatter

\chapter*{Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\TOCcols

\addtocounter{SECTION}{1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION~\theSECTION}%
\section*{Section~\theSECTION}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut \Sum{labore} et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Sum{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \Sum{fugiat} nulla pariatur. \Sum{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}

\addtocounter{SECTION}{1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION~\theSECTION}%
\section*{Section~\theSECTION}%
Lorem ipsum \Sum{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \Sum{ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur \Sum{sint} occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\addtocounter{SECTION}{1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION~\theSECTION}%
\section*{Section~\theSECTION}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut \Sum{labore} et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \Sum{reprehenderit} in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu \Sum{fugiat} nulla pariatur. \Sum{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}

\addtocounter{SECTION}{1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION~\theSECTION}%
\section*{Section~\theSECTION}%
Lorem ipsum \Sum{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \Sum{ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur \Sum{sint} occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\addtocounter{SECTION}{1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION~\theSECTION}%
\section*{Section~\theSECTION}%
Lorem ipsum \Sum{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \Sum{ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur \Sum{sint} occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have obviously worked hard on you code. But, having become a GFOM (Grumpy Forgetfull Old Man), I don't really understand it. However from a document reader's point of view I don't see the relationship between the section text entries in your ToC with the section texts in the document.

Comment: Absolutely fine. The relationship is the `\Sum{}` command. the ToC contains the section titles and whatever I wrap the the `\Sum{}`. So for example if I wrote `\section{Section 1} The three \Sum{monkeys} on the branch are \Sum{hungry}.` The unformatted text of the ToC would be Section 1 Monkeys. Hungry.

Comment: @Faergen You don't need to use TOC machinery because there is no page numbers in your  "TOC". You can create your own file using `\openout` and `\write` and read this file in the `\TOCcols` macro. This approach solves all your three problems. I have prepared an example with this but some users @Ingmar @Rolland @FHZ @Zarko @JoséCarlosSantos close this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your first problem.

Replace:

```
 \renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\vspace{-3cm}
```

with

```
   \renewcommand{\printtottitle}[1]{}   
   \renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\vspace{-3cm}}
```

For your other problems look at the contents of the TOC file and see what you might be able to do with your `\Sum` macro to adjust them. (A wild guess, try `\addtocontents` instead of `\addcontentsline`)